# Why does the Datasheet for the ATMEGA88 have two pins for PORT D bit 5 (with different functions, too)?

Tags: microcontroller, datasheet

The [ATMEGA88 Datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Atmel%20PDFs/ATmega48_88_168_Automotive_2-9-15.pdf) has two pins for PD5 on page 3 for the TQFP layout. Those pins being Pin 9 and Pin 12. Normally, I wouldn't blink twice, but It seems that both pins have different functions. Is this a typo, or intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pin 12 very likely is PB0. Check page 64.

This Atmel [datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/atmel/2545S.pdf) and the Microchip [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2545-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48-88-168_Summary.pdf) and [this one](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2545-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48-88-168_Datasheet.pdf) confirm.